# How to modify Chrome interface?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

First I would like to say I am not entirely certain that I am in the correct area of Stack Overflow with regards to this question. If I am not, apologies in advance.

I am wondering, can I modify Chrome this way- I would like to create a vertical "view" of tabs and eliminate horizontal tabs. Can I build an extension to do this? It should be retractable to hide the tabs.

Can this be done with HTML and CSS?

Comment: It isn't possible to directly modify Chrome's UI.